# Serializing a string with backslash

Tags: c#, replace

My program should process an input string. But when "\mesg" is sent in Method1, the else block is executed instead of the if block.

```
 void Method()
 {
     string str = "\\Mesg";
     str = Method1(str);
     Console.WriteLine(str);
 }

 string Method1(string s)
 {
     string upadtedString = s;
     if (s.Contains(@"\\"))
     {
         //do nothing
     }
     else if(s.Contains(@"\"))
     {
         upadtedString.Replace(@"\",@"\\");
         s = upadtedString;
     }
     return s;
 }
```

The best example is when "\0Mesg" is the input to `Method1()`. This raises an XML serilaziation exception when I try to deserialze. Just to handle this I want to add another slash, "\0Mesg", before serialzing the string.

How can I make it work as expected?

Comment: Please provide some code which compiles but doesn't do what you want.

Comment: This: `s.Contains("\")` will not compile. You need to escape the `\\`.

Comment: "\\Mesg" is the string: "\Mesg" so it should be in the else block.

Comment: @starz26 Are you clear that \0 there is no actual slash, it is just a representation so you can out put special character into a string. Adding a slash in front of this character when it is passed to your method won't actually change the character. You probably should be removing the character instead in the example of "\0Mesg". Something like s = s.TrimStart('\0')

Answer (score 2):

Your first conditional will fail, as it's searching for a double slash, while `str` contains a single slash.

```
Console.WriteLine(@"\\");  // Double slash
Console.WriteLine("\\");   // Single slash
Console.WriteLine("\\\\"); // Double slash
Console.WriteLine(@"\");   //"// Single slash
```

---

`str` will not produce what you expect it to return, since `\` is an escape character.

```
string str = "\\Mesg";
Console.WriteLine(str); // Returns: "\Mesg"
```

Try this instead

```
string myString = "\\Mesg";
Console.WriteLine(myString); // Returns: \Mesg
Console.WriteLine(EscapeSlashes(myString)); //Returns; \\Mesg

public static string EscapeSlashes(string str)
{
    return str.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
}
```

Comment: NO i would get the string as "\tMesg" or "\0Mesg". THis is input i get. I have to modify the input but caanot ask to send input as "\\\\Mesg"

Comment: @starz26: You would have to elaborate. I don't understand what you mean if my answer didn't answer you.

Comment: I meant i cannot ask the sender of input to send data as "\\Mesg". when sender sends "\Mesg" , I have to modify in my application to check, replace such chars with an additonal slash so tht i dont get exception when i serialze the string finally

Comment: @starz26: Look at the last code-block to see if I understand you correctly.

Comment: ya but I need to apply this convertion on \0,\t,\b,\n etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is basically correct, you are missing something important for it to work though...

```
void Method() 
{  
    string str = "\\Mesg"; 
    str = Method1(str);  
    Console.WriteLine(str); 
}

string Method1(string s)
{
    string upadtedString = s;
    if (s.Contains(@"\\")
    {
     //do nothing
    }
    else if(s.Contains(@"\"))
    {
          s = upadtedString.Replace(@"\",@"\\");//Change around here
    }
    return s;
}
```

You need to grab what is being replaced. upadtedString.Replace() does NOT modify the string itself, it returns the modified string.